# Sass incoherent indentation during assets precompilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, assets, precompile

I am trying to run `rake assets:precompile` before my deployment and I keep havig this error :

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Inconsistent indentation: 1 tab was used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 1 space.
  (in /home/me/workspace/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass)
(sass):16
```

I've tried to turn tabs into spaces with `expand --tabs=2 app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass` but it's inneffective.

I've also tried to delete line 16 from `app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass` but the trace was still exactly the same so the `(sass):16` line may refer to an error id.

I did `expand --tabs=2` with all of my stylesheets but nothing changed.

EDIT

To change tabs into spaces quickly, I recommand using vim and typing this :

```
:set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
:retab
:wq
```

Or adding the first line to your .vimrc and then just typing the 2 final lines.

Comment: Maybe this error is raised by a file called in application.sass... Check all you .sass files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesky error - tabs and spaces are actually different characters

The bottom line is that you'll have a tab somewhere, whereas you'll be using a single space in the other stylesheets of your application.

--

**Debug**

Personally, I'll be looking at removing every "dependency" from your application.css.sass file, and then slowly adding them one-by-one again. This will give you the most informed idea on where the issue will reside (if I were a betting man, I'd say it would be in one of your dependent files!)

As with most software bug fixes, the solution will be to cut it down to the bare essentials, and then build it up piece-by-piece again

Comment: BTW if you post your `application.css.sass`, it will certainly be a big help in finding what the errors are

Comment: Funny. I removed all dependencies and now I get : `rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Inconsistent indentation: 2 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 1 tab.
  (in /home/me/workspace/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/gmn_webclient.sass)
(sass):79
` so I'll try editing that file

Comment: Hmmm okay. First of all, this file looks like a dependency to me - get rid of all the "require" calls at the top of `application.css.sass` and then try the precompile again. If it works, it means you've got indentation inconsistencies with your other stylesheets

Comment: I got rid of all the "require", that was what I meant by "I removed all dependencies". It's included from my `config/environments/production.rb` file in `config.assets.precompile += %w( ... some files )`

Comment: Hmm okay- can you try commenting out that line? If it works, you'll have to go into `gwm_webclient.sass` and change the indentation :)

Comment: It worked fine ! I've tried to change the indentation with `expand --tabs=2 path/to/file` with all my stylesheets, shouldn't I have only spaces now ? What else could I do to change the indentation ?

Comment: I have a little saying which is "the right way is always the hardest" -- in this case, the "right" way would be to manually indent every SASS file :)